# How can I get google search's result?It had better be Json

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-search

just like "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=text&format=json&page=" I can get the result searching in wekipedia.It can return a Json.

How can I get the result searching in google?

Answer (score 2):

Google Search has an api here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

It's free for the first 100 searches, and $5 for extra 1000 queries (like if you need 10,000 queries in a day, you pay $50).